# Textbox blank out valid value after erroneous input - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, mvvm, data-binding

So, I have a simple view containing a Textbox and a Label.

```
<TextBox x:Name="MyIntTextBox" Text="{Binding MyInt, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, Mode=TwoWay, StringFormat={}{D2}}"/>        
<Label Content="{Binding MyStr2}"/>
```

And in the `ViewModel`, I have:

```
private decimal myInt;

public decimal MyInt
{
    get { return myInt; }
    set
    {
        if (value == myInt) { return; }
        myInt = value;               
        OnPropertyChange();
        OnPropertyChange("MyStr2");
    }
}

public string MyStr2
{
    get
    {
        return myInt.ToString("N2", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-IN"));
    }

}
```

Simply speaking, the `TextBox` `Text` is bound to a `decimal` value, and the `Label` is supposed display the value in the `textbox` with proper formatting.

Since I have `LostFocus` as my `UpdateSourceTrigger`in `TextBox`, I press `TAB` in order for the `validation` and `binding` to work.

So when I enter a `decimal` value, everything works properly. The `Label` properly displays the formatted number.

[image: Properly working]

And when I enter some garbage non-decimal value, the `TextBox` `Border` turns red indicating validation error.

[image: error]

But, when I put some valid value after that, like this...

[image: valid input]

...and then focus out of the `TextBox`, bam! The `TextBox` goes blank.

[image: blank textbox]

The `Label` however indicates the correct value. I set up breakpoints in the `ViewModel`, and I can see that `MyInt` does have the correct value, in this case, 600, but the `TextBox` does not display it.

I also get the following error in my `Output` Window:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 6 : 'StringFormat' converter failed to convert value '600' (type 'Decimal'); fallback value will be used, if available. BindingExpression:Path=MyInt; DataItem='ViewModel' (HashCode=37975124); target element is 'TextBox' (Name='MyIntTextBox'); target property is 'Text' (type 'String') FormatException:'System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format, ParamsArray args)
   at System.String.FormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format, ParamsArray args)
   at System.String.Format(IFormatProvider provider, String format, Object[] args)
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.ConvertHelper(IValueConverter converter, Object value, Type targetType, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture)'
```

Is there any simple workaround for this? Or is it something I am doing wrong?

Comment: try removing if (value == myInt) { return; }

Comment: Doesn't help. Still getting the blank textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But, when I put some valid value after that, like this...

It will work again if you type in a `decimal` value into the `TextBox`.

But the workaround would otherwise be to implement your own custom converter class that handles the conversion between `decimal` and `string`.

Try this:

```
namespace WpfApp2
{
    class DecimalToStringConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value == null)
                return null;

            return System.Convert.ToDecimal(value).ToString(parameter as string);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            decimal d;
            if (decimal.TryParse(value.ToString(), out d))
                return d;

            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
<StackPanel xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2">
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <local:DecimalToStringConverter x:Key="conv" />
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <TextBox x:Name="MyIntTextBox" Text="{Binding MyInt, Converter={StaticResource conv}, ConverterParameter=0.00}"/>
    <Label Content="{Binding MyStr2}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: `It will work again if you type in a decimal value into the TextBox.`
It doesnt. Anyway, your solution worked perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The solution of mm8 is good but fails with nullable decimals.
Here is a fixed ConvertBack function:

```
public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (decimal.TryParse(value.ToString(), out var d))
         return d;

    if (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(targetType) != null)
        return null;
    else
        return 0m;
}
```